# Loging in using Mechanize

Tags: python, cookies, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to extract some data from a website - not a lot - but enough to warrant a little script... I am attempting to first log in to the site https://squashlevels.com using `mechanize` and `cookielib`, but I am failing...

I currently have

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib2 
import cookielib
import mechanize

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()

br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://squashlevels.com/menu_login.php")

# How do I log in?

r = requests.get('https://squashlevels.com/players.php?all&club=1314')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

## Do stuff...
```

What code should I be using to log into this site?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using just `requests`, I'm not really sure `mechanize` would provide any additional value. By utilizing `requests.Session`, you maintain the cookies returned by the login process to include when requesting `players.php`.

The minor wrench that the site throws into the mix is the fact that you also need to post the MD5 hash of the password:

```
email = 'user@host.com'
password = 'secret'

s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://squashlevels.com/menu_login.php', data={
    'action': 'login',
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
    'md5password': hashlib.md5(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
})

r = s.get('https://squashlevels.com/players.php?all&club=1314')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('table.ranking tr'):
    print([col.text.strip() for col in row.select('td')])
```

Output:

```
['1', 'Nathan Miller', 'Bluecoat Sports Horsham', 'East England Masters 2018/19', '6', '15 Dec 2018', '4,706', '70%', '']
['2', 'Kit Pearman', 'Dorking', 'Surrey Winter League 2018/19', '2', '20 Nov 2018', '4,469', '64%', '']
['3', 'Simon Millard', 'Bluecoat Sports Horsham', 'Sussex Mens League 2018/2019', '1', '04 Dec 2018', '2,680', '57%', '']
...
```

Comment: I get `NameError("name 'hashlib' is not defined",)
`, I assume I need to update my request library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to log in.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 

email = 'username@email.com'
password = 'password'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://squashlevels.com/menu_login.php')

# log in
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit'][value='Login']").click()

# get the html then do some stuff
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: `mechanize` would not be able to handle this use case easily as the markup on this page is a bit weird - form controls are actually outside of the form itself, *the form itself is empty*:

```
<form action="menu_login.php" method="POST" class="login" data-op-form-id="1"></form>
```

this leads to `mechanize` detecting *0 "controls" inside the login form*.

The submit button behavior is controlled via javascript.